# How to build a known apk for play store in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

i made app and build it as an apk file in flutter and i tried to install it in my android phone but while installing it, play store said: the app is unkhown do you wanna install,
and then i installed the app and app was working well, the question is how i can solve it, Do i have to buy a play store account? or there is another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to make the app available to play store users then you need to create a play store account. Normally the warning that you received if from Android OS telling the user that the app can't not be trusted, since it does not come from the play store but yourself built it. You can ignore this "warning" for now.

The warning will not be shown to the users when the app is built, signed and uploaded to play store.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the official documentation to know how to sign and publish your binary file to the Play Store.

You'll need 25$ to create the Play Store developer account (available for your entire lifetime) and a bit of reading from the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)